# Is it a bug in PhoneTextBox in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

After applying a style to the PhoneTextBox, something happened strangely. First I entered some text in it, then I deleted the text from phonetextbox without losing the focus, then I enter some text again, but the text can't be seen. But when the PhoneTextbox got focused, the text shown up again.

Any thoughts on this issus? Thanks.

Edit：
the Style defined as:

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneTextBoxStyle" TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="LengthIndicatorBorder">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="LengthIndicator" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="HintBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="HintContent" Background="Transparent" Content="{TemplateBinding Hint}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,5,3,0" Style="{TemplateBinding HintStyle}" 
                                                Foreground="White"
                                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ActualHintVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" 
                                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                Foreground="White"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="TextBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="Transparent" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="Text" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" 
                                     FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" 
                                     FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" 
                                     SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" 
                                     TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" 
                                     Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ActionIconBorder" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="54">
                            <Image x:Name="ActionIcon" Height="54" Source="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}" Width="54"/>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementTextBlock" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="8" Opacity="0" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Please include the whole question and the style you're applying. Just linking to questions on other forums/sites is not an appropriate use of SO.

Comment: @Matt Lacey Hi, Matt, thanks for tip. I've edited the queston.

Comment: Same issue. Clearing and entering text will change the foreground color. It happens a bit differently depending on the theme (dark/light). No time to investigate.